# CSS relative positioning to parent and other children

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a problem with positioning my `<div>` elements. I have the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/5tv4pyh0/1/

As you can see, the second child is positioned below the first one. What I want to achieve is to have the second child at the same top position as the first one as long as they do not overflow each other. If the second child would have `left: 30%` it should appear below the first child.

Using `position: absolute` for the children also doesn't work because both children can have a flexible height. I also tried to add `float: left` but then both children always appear next to each other regardless what I set to `left`.

Any suggestions how I can achieve the desired behavior?

**Edit:**

I'm trying to create a grid like positioning with only setting the x-position to the child elements. Then if the two children have the same x-position or the second child has a x-position that is within the width of the first child the second should appear below the first element. If the second child has a x-position next to the first child it should be positioned at the same y-position.

Thanks, Gerry

Comment: What does "as long as they don't overflow each other" mean?

Comment: Have you tried setting the children elements in question to display as `inline-block`? This will position nested elements alongside each other, and if you remove the inline `left` values you can align them center as well by declaring `text-align: center` on the parent element.

Comment: do you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/x3sbosrc/ as @UncaughtTypeError said.

Comment: @Roope: https://jsfiddle.net/5tv4pyh0/2/ shows what I mean with "as long as they don't overflow each other". Using this example, I want "Child 2" to be positioned below "Child 1".

Comment: @Bhansa: No, that's not what I'm looking for. I need a defined left position but a top position according to the parent and other child elements.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x3sbosrc/1/ check this.

Comment: @Gery If you want to `float` them you can use `margin-left` instead of `left`. There are `flex` rules that work well for alignment, for example; if you need the second child to always stick to the left, as long as it has space to.

Answer (score 0):

Make Following changes in your CSS :
you will have to add display: inline-block for child class and remove position: relative attribute for same

I added 80% width for the first child of the child just for test purpose.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  /*position: relative;*/
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child:first-child {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child" style="height: 50px; left: 10%;">child 1</div>
  <div class="child" style="height: 30px; left: 40%;">child 2</div>
</div>
```